Reference request on Bertrand Russell
Bertrand Russell allegedly wrote “Thus mathematics may be defined as the subject in which we never know what we are talking about, nor whether what we are saying is true.” Where did he write it, if at all?

You can find the full reference on the MMA website

@user6530:   You mean MAA

@user6530 Many thanks - please write up an answer!
